# How to add CSS and JS files in core Python without using Flask & Django?

Tags: python

As per my personal interest, I tried a lot for adding CSS & JS files in my basic form without using Flask & Django. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that, you need to output your CSS and JS file directly to the HTML file.
For example, if you have the folder structure as follows:

```
|
Root App
|__ assets
|   |__ css
|   |_______style.css
|   |__ Js
|   |_______ myjs.js
|__ bin
|   |__app.py
|
|__ templates
|___________maintemplate.html
|___________demoform.html
```

You can create a route to output the file by reading it, Please check following code

in your **app.py** file

```
import web
import os
routs = (
    '/','index',
   '/staticFiles','loadStatic'
    )
app = web.application(routs, globals())
render = web.template.render('templates/',base="maintemplate")
class index(object):
    def GET(self):
        return render.demoform()
class loadStatic(object):
    def GET(self):
        form = web.input(fileName='',filePath='')
        fileName=form.file
        filePath=form.folder 
        script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__) #<-- absolute dir the script is in
        rel_path = ("../assets/%s/%s" % (filePath,fileName))
        abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)
        temp = open(abs_file_path,'r').read()
        return temp
```

In your **maintemplate.html**

```
$def with (content)
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title> SAMPLE CODE </title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="staticFiles?file=style.css&folder=css" /> 
    <script src="staticFiles?file=myjs.js&folder=js"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    $:content 
</body> 
</html>
```

**How It Works**
In app.py, like all CDN CSS/JS links, we are reading the file and returning output to the browser as a HTTP request.